# Scale Map Markers by Zoom, Android

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview, google-maps-markers

I have  lot of markers on my map. Zooming in each marker shows me a position. but zooming out the markers are overlapping each other and it is more difficult do determine the position of a marker.

Is there a way to scale the marker image depending on the zoom factor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on how you draw your marker. If your marker is just a bitmap/drawable, simply use `matrix.postScale()`

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(2f, 2f); // douple the size
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, matrix, mPaint);
```

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed method of how to do this?

Comment: @ferguior: What exactly do you need? Drawing a scaled image is now answered in me edited post...

Comment: My doubt is more about how to handle the scaling, when to do it and how to measure it so that I can apply the right scale. Also, this code you posted, in which class would it go? In the Maps View, or in the OverlayItem, or in the ItemizedItem?

Comment: @ferguior: The calculation for the scaling might be tricky and I think you just need to play with it to find a good scaling factor. The code I posted should be implemented where you draw your marker/overlay. Short check revealed that you can use the `draw()` method in `ItemizedOverlay`

Answer (score 3):

Markers do not change size based on zoom. Use GroundOverlays if you desire this effect. [src](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_a_marker)

```
 GoogleMap map = ...; // get a map.
 BitmapDescriptor image = ...; // get an image.
 LatLngBounds bounds = ...; // get a bounds
 // Adds a ground overlay with 50% transparency.
 GroundOverlay groundOverlay = map.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
     .image(image)
     .positionFromBounds(bounds)
     .transparency(0.5));
```

A ground overlay is an image that is fixed to a map and scales with the map zoom. Please see the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay?hl=en) for more info

Comment: But then you have to calculate the bounds of the Ground Overlay rather than supplying a position. This makes it a less than ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

A simple form is.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.raw.ic_car_1);
BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap); 
        googleMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
             .image(bitmapDescriptor)
             .position(latLng,100));
```