# How to adjust maker size when zoom in and zoom out

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]

[image]

---

As in above images ,marker always visible even if zoom out completely and all marker are getting attach together completely when zoom out

So how to adjust maker size while zoom in and zoom out as in below images

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> If you need to change the markers size according to zoom out and in, then need to implement  onCameraMove() listener and according to zoom level you need to change the icon of marker added as below

```
override fun onCameraMove() {
 var zoomlevel = map.cameraPosition.zoom
        if (zoomlevel < 6) {
            marker1?.apply {
                setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_yellow_xs))
            }
        }
        else if (zoomlevel <= 10) {
            marker1?.apply {
                setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_yellow_small))
            }
        }
        else if (zoomlevel <= 12) {
            marker1?.apply {
                setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_yellow_med_small))
            }
        }
}
```

> Make sure marker images **size** should be increased with increasing **zoom** level, Hence you need to change images of marker according to the zoom level in camera move listener. Let me know if this works!

Comment: sir can we use same icon instead of using three different icon  and resize it while zoom in and zoom out if so then please provide me that code

Comment: We can't use same icon, you need to resize the icons according to zoom level with different image sizes then only you can see proper images will zoom out or in.

Comment: You can check these two links if it works:
1> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15685465/5786187 
2> https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520062/5786187